# Can't browse collections of new MongoDB in Retool?

Tags: database, mongodb, retool

I'm using Retool to connect to MongoDB. I've set up the resource and the connection was successful. However, when I attempt to build a query in Retool, it makes me select the "collection" but I cannot get my collection to appear - it's showing no collections available.

I've confirmed in MongoDB's admin portal that I do infact have a collection + data in that collection.

Why can I not see it in Retool? Do I need to adjust my resource connection to specifically look for my collection?

Comment: Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328576/not-getting-mongodb-collections-via-retool-query/74334769#74334769) to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem myself too. I was able to get it to work by following the steps here:
https://retool.com/blog/building-a-listing-approval-tool-in-mongodb/

More specifically:

> All you’ll need to get started is a MongoDB cluster loaded with their sample_airbnb dataset. MongoDB Cloud has a pretty generous free tier and great documentation, so you’re in good hands. If you already have a cluster up and running, you can add sample datasets to it through clicking on the 3 dots on your cluster homepage, and selecting “Load Sample Dataset.”

1. Get your link from MDB, should look like this: `mongodb+srv://gagejustins:<password>@retool-test-betz7.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
2. Remove the end of the link after mongodb.net/ and replace it with the database name. In this case the name was sample_airbnb. Your completed link should look like this: `mongodb+srv://gagejustins:<password>@retool-test-betz7.azure.mongodb.net/sample_airbnb`

Dont forget to change the `<password>` with your database password.