# not getting mongoDB collections via retool query

Tags: mongodb, collections, retool

I've connected mongoDB as a resource for retool and created a query for it in my retool app, but the queries don't really work for me. The action query "listCollections" goes through but it gets wrong info on those collections but the action query "find" and other actions report the error message "Collection names cannot be empty". Where is the problem, I can't figure it out!

Thank you for the attention! Hope anyone can reach out and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it started at the same time as yours, this worked for me try doing the following:
1- Goto MongoDB->"Data Access" and provide your user "admin" status
2- Open Retool Query library add a new Resource using the connection string of user you just made admin.
3- Test the connection and save it.
4- Refresh retool and try again.
Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Looks like the problem is solved, but then I've tried with a read-only user and it was working that way too, maybe just a connection problem.

So to my future self, always update the editor page after making changes into the mongoDB database!